# i want to use carbon format time with jquery but I don't nkow how to convert jquery data to php

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, time, format

[I want to use carbon format time with juery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRLrm.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: Please don't post images but add the code directly in the editor and formatting it properly.

Comment: @commonsense I got a good laugh from your comment once I saw your username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the code you posted is within a script tag inside a blade file, it is not possible to use Carbon inside of an external JavaScript file.

Comment: var time = item.START_TIME;

                            if (time!= null) {
                                start_time =  '{{Carbon\Carbon::parse(' +time+ ')->format('g:i A')}}';
                            }else {
                                start_time = '';
                            }

Comment: I do like this but it not work

Comment: but if i do that code below it work:

Comment: var time = item.START_TIME;

                            if (time!= null) {

                                start_time =  '{{Carbon\Carbon::parse('16:22:42.4245847')->format('g:i A')}}';
                            }else {
                                start_time = '';
                            }

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you'll be able to pull in a JavaScript variable inside the blade {{ }} tags. You are better off using JavaScripts Date() object or using moment.js

Comment: #Polari  ok thanks you I will try with that way

Comment: start_time =  moment('09:14:53.1497123','HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm a');

Comment: I used this code with moment js than it work now thank you